# Return value from a subscript in ksh

Tags: ksh

I want to call a script from inside a script like below

```
weeknum=$(getweek )
```

Here getweek is a script file. How to write the sub script file so that it returns the value to weeknum. Should i use return or exit with status as return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very well use `echo` for that purpose.

```
$ cat new
echo 1
$ number=$(./new)
$ echo $number
1
```

I think that serves the purpose. Also note that `new` above is the script that you're gonna write.

*comment below if I mis-assumed something*

Answer (score 1):

The `$(cmd)` syntax captures the *standard output* of `cmd` (stripped of trailing newline characters).

So all you have to do is have `getweek` output the information:

```
#! /bin/sh -
date +%V # or %U or %W
```

`date` outputs the week number on its stdout which it inherits from `sh`, which in the case of `weeknum=$(getweek)` is set to a pipe or socketpair by the shell at the other end of which the shell reads that output to store in the `weeknum` variable.

You could also return the week number in the exit status:

```
#! /bin/sh -
exit "$(date +%W)"
```

Which you obtain with:

```
getweek
weeknum=$?
```

but I would advise against that. The exit status should be reserved for error reporting or limited to true/false values.

Typically above, if there's an error (in forking a process, in executing `date` or `sh`) or the process is killed, you'll get a non-zero exit status which should not be treated as a *week number*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one

`output=$(sh <scriptname>)`

And I feel in this case you can also try writing a function with in your script which should help to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Put value to the stdout using any command and read it.

```
# somesubscript
# do something
echo "my value is here"   # echo is a method to put something to the stdout
```

Give execute priv. for subscript:

```
chmod a+rx somesubscript
```

And use it

```
val=$(./somesubscript)
echo "$val" # will echo my value is here
```

return and exit is used to tell caller was it okay or not. Not for return values.