# Return long integer value from a function in ksh

Tags: ksh

I use the below function in ksh to return the long value of date parts

```
function convert_date_to_long {
    long_date="${1}${2}${3}"

    return $long_date;
}
```

but the result i get is `209` when i pass the parameters `2015 02 25` .

How do i get the long value `20150225`?

Comment: Why don't you do the same thing as you as [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256239/38906)?

Comment: i tried it . so instead of return i gave echo $long_date but when i call the $? to get the value it returns 0

Comment: Yes, because the `echo` command success. What do you actually want?

Comment: For me it is [working](http://pastebin.com/2hmdz7gM) as expected

Comment: My requirement is to return the above value 20150225. Using return command it used to work for smaller numbers. But not sure why it is not allowed for large values

Comment: Got it !. So i should assign function to a variable as mentioned in the other post for echo to work.  Thanks ! `long_date=$(convert_date_to_long $year $month $day)`

Answer (score 0):

`return` sets the exit status of the function, and this is a number between `0` and `255`. If the number is larger than that, you get its value mod 256, and `20150225 % 256` is `209`.

To get a string as output from a function, the function should echo it, and then you can capture it in the caller with command substution.

```
function convert_date_to_long {
    echo "${1}${2}${3}"
}

some_var=$(convert_date_to_long 2015 02 25)
```